# HTML and CSS rectangle not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a site where there is some text telling the user about the site. I want to draw a white rectangle behind the text to separate it from the background.

I am able to draw the rectangle, but the rectangle draws over the text.

I am using the below CSS code to draw the rectangle:

```
#rect1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is the HTML in the main page:

```
<body>
  <div class="container_24">
    <header>
      <h1>Omicrome</h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="# " class=s elected>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
          <li><a href="software.html">Projects</a ></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div class="banner grid_18" href="about.html">
        <a href="logic.html" class="button" id="new">View Article</a>
        <h2>

        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class=" grid_8 callout"></div>
      <a href="gallery.html" class="button" id="spacesoft">View Gallery</a>
    </header>
    <div id="rect1"></div>
    <div class="main clearfix">
      <div class="grid_9">
        <h3>About The Site</h3>
        <p>Here at Omicrome we are always coming up with new and innovative ideas for the future and for the present. These ideas are researched and expanded upon to make them a reality. View our ideas in the article section and see them come to life in
          the project section. Our many project's range from software to hardware, Huge build's to small and fun one day project's. We are all about space and technology...
          <p><a href="about.html" class="button">Find Out More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid_9">
        <h3>Our Content</h3>
        <p>We post a variety of ideas and project's based around space and technology. Some of them include a hand held cheap computer, software to teach people about space and snapshot's of stellar and interstellar objects visible from our telescope. We
          ask questions like "Why dont we have a robotic Mars colony?" and find an answer or solution. </p>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p> </p>
        <p><a href="about.html" class="button">Find Out More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid_6">
      </div>
```

The

```
<div id "rect1></div>
```

is the part that says draw a rectangle in the html code. How can I get it to draw the rectangle behind the text?

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
z-index: -1;
```

to the `#rect1`:

```
#rect1{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qzj2w9q/)

(You should probably also adjust the rectangle size to make it look better.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use absolute position, set its `z-index` to `-1`.
But I think you might just want to give the `div` or `span` that contains the text a different background and border instead of drawing a new div behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
             #rect1{
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background: #eee;
                z-index:-1;
                 }
        </style>
    </head>
       <body>

   <div class = "container_24">
   <header>
   <h1>Omicrome</h1>
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="# " class = selected>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="articles.html">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="software.html">Projects</a ></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class = "banner grid_18" href="about.html">
   <a href="logic.html"  class="button" id ="new">View Article</a>
    <h2>

    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class=" grid_8 callout"></div>
   <a href="gallery.html"  class="button" id ="spacesoft">View Gallery</a>
</header>

<div id = "rect1"></div>


<div class = "main clearfix">
<div class ="grid_9">
<h3>About The Site</h3>
<p>Here at Omicrome we are always coming up with new and innovative ideas for the future and for the present. These ideas are researched and expanded upon to make them a reality. View our ideas in the article section and see them come to life in the project section. Our many project's range from software to hardware, Huge build's to small and fun one day project's. We are all about space and technology...
   <p><a href="about.html"  class="button">Find Out More</a></p>
   </div>
   <div class ="grid_9">
   <h3>Our Content</h3>
   <p>We post a variety of ideas and project's based around space and     technology. Some of them include a hand held cheap computer, software to teach people about space and snapshot's of stellar and interstellar objects visible from our telescope. We ask questions like "Why dont we have a robotic Mars  colony?" and find an answer or solution. </p><p>
</p><p>  </p>

  <p><a href="about.html" class="button">Find Out More</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class ="grid_6">


  </div>
</html>
```

Thats your code.. Moreover you can use bootstrap classes like well to separate your div text from the other content if you wish to.

I kept the background-color to be #eee so that you can see it. Edit it according to your need.